# Hide a Field on Flutter Form Builder

Tags: flutter, forms, field, hide, formbuilder

Let's say we want to pass an ID on form submission but we don't want the users to see it, on [flutter_form_builder: ^7.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) there is no option to hide fields, any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that [flutter_form_builder: ^7.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) offers to build your own custom field, so if we want to make a hidden field, we just return a SizedBox.shrink() on builder and set the initial value on FormBuilderField.Heres a sample code.

```js
   Widget taskIDField() {
            return FormBuilderField(
              name: "task_id",
              enabled: false,
              initialValue: widget.task?.id.toString(),
              validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
              ]),
              builder: (FormFieldState<dynamic> field) {
                //Empty widget
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              },
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this idea.
I prefer to use the Visibility widget from flutter due fully needs the field will be created with his keyname. Remember to set the maintainState to true for the widget keep alive even not visible. If not, the widget will be not created.

```
              Visibility(
                visible: false ,
                maintainState: true,
                child: FormBuilderCheckbox(
                  focusNode: participoFocus,
                  autofocus: false,
                  initialValue: true,
                  name: 'namekey',
                  autovalidateMode:
                  AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                    FormBuilderValidators.required(
                        errorText: 'Required'),
                  ]),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Hint Text',
                    labelText: 'Label',
                    icon: Icon(Icons.done_all_sharp),
                  ),
                  title: const Text('Tittle'),
                ),
              ),
```